# Browse a Thunderbird mailstorage file?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird respectively Icedove for Mail.

For every box (inbox, outbox, sent, ...) there is a file.
If I open it with an editor I can find the mails inside.
I can see mail- and mime-headers but I do not know the exact format.

If anyone knows at least the name of the overall format that would be helpful to find a browser by myself.

Is there a small browser that does parse that mail-storage-files and shows them in an nice way.

No need for mail-handling needed - only offline view of a mail-file.

Answer (score 2):

Each individual message is written using the [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) format (also 822 & 5322). That's the standard Internet Email format (SMTP servers always exchange RFC 2822-formatted messages).

All messages together are stored in a [mbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) file, although recently Thunderbird has begun using [Maildir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) for new accounts by default. (Both formats hold the same RFC 822 messages, but Maildir has one file per message, not per folder, therefore less likely to get corrupted.)

Both formats are very common in Unix-like systems for storing mail; they're recognized by IMAP/POP3 servers, and the `(neo)mutt` and `((re)al)pine` terminal-based email apps can browse them as well.

(Note that Mbox has several [variants](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/mail-mbox-formats.html) which differ in how they handle lines starting with `From␣`. I am not sure which is used by Thunderbird, but it could be detected by receiving a test message and checking how it got stored.)

---

Because both formats are "flat" and finding the desired message in a giant file or directory is a bit slow, most software using them will tend to invent an indexing or caching system alongside it. For example, Thunderbird creates `*.msf` index files using a format called [Mork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_(file_format)). (See [also](https://www.jwz.org/blog/2011/07/mork-keeps-on-giving-when-the-database-worms-eat-into-your-murder-trial/).)

These `.msf` index files can be safely ignored; they are not part of the actual mbox/Maildir format.

Comment: mutt -f <mboxfile> is exactly what I was looking. But is there a tool that gives me a GUI too?

Comment: The variants link is dead, see the wayback machine cache here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20201231033049/https://jdebp.eu/FGA/mail-mbox-formats.html